# Does not receive data from API by asynchronous function FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

I want to receive data from an API and for that I created a SERVICE:

```
class ApiService {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
    try {

      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Config.apiURL));
      debugPrint('Response code: ${response.statusCode}');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> data=jsonDecode(response.body) as List<dynamic>;
         debugPrint('in service:${data.toString()}');

        return data ;  
      }
      else{
      debugPrint('else');
      return [];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Failed to fetch data..");
    }
  }
}
```

And I called him from `StatefulWidget`:

```
    void getData() async {
 
        debugPrint('entrance');
        userDataList= await ApiService().getData();
        debugPrint(userDataList.toString());  
  } 

    @override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint('init');
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }
```

And for some reason I am not receiving data.Would love your help.

Comment: you need to call `setState` after you assigned the `userDataList`. (or do the assignement inside a `setState`)

Comment: Try to change your function like this Future<void> getData() {}. And inside initState you can isolate your function like this :  
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
   await getData();
  });

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in more than one way, two of them can be:

**1) using setState in the Future**

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<dynamic> data = [];

  Future<void> presentData() async {
    await ApiService().getData().then((value) => setState(() {
          data = value;
        }));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    presentData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: data.isEmpty
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('${data[index]}',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**2) using StreamBuilder**

remembering that you are dealing with a streamController, so consider the dispose()

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  StreamController<List<dynamic>> dataStreamController = StreamController();

  List<dynamic> data = [];

  Future<void> presentData() async {
    data = await ApiService().getData();

    dataStreamController.add(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    presentData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
        stream: dataStreamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('${snapshot.data![index]}',
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dataStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

ApiService class:

```dart
class ApiService {
  Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
    List data = [];
    try {
      var response = await http
          .get(Uri.parse(config.apiUrl));
      debugPrint('Response code: ${response.statusCode}');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        try {
          data = (jsonDecode(response.body))
              .map((e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>)
              .toList();

          return data;
        } catch (err) {
          print(err);
          return [];
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint('else');
        return [];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch data..');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Flutter devtool network inspector to see what is the response of your request. Also check that your device can well reach internet : no dns issue, proxy, vpn errors.

If your method is call and never respond, maybe check the version of http used  ? Old one ?

To help you, i need more :

- log
- package version
- flutter version
- device used

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see that it happens when trying to contact certain API'S, for example here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos brings all the data. What could this be related to?

Comment: I need logs mate. What is the response of the api. What happen in the dev tool, timeout ? 500 or 200 ?

Comment: Now I see it has "XMLHttpRequest error" error

Comment: So something is wrong with your request. Can you share here the complete Curl ?